# How to Sentence Tokenize a List of Strings while maintaining the information of what strings constitute each sentence?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, tokenize

I have a list of strings as below(found from an OCR on a pdf) , and for each string in the list, I also have the co-ordinates of their position in the pdf

```
["Much of Singapore's infrastructure had been destroyed during the war",  
"including those needed to supply utilities."
"A shortage of food led to malnutrition, disease,"  
" and rampant crime and violence."   
"A series of strikes in 1947 caused massive",    
"stoppages in public transport and other services." ]
```

I want to sentence tokenize the "concatenated list" (the blob of text created if I concatenate each item in the list) , but I also want to keep the info of which items in the list constitute each sentence.

Currently, I am simply concatenating each item in the list --> feeding it to nltk/spacy --> getting sentences.  I get the below result:

```
["Much of Singapore's infrastructure had been destroyed during the war,‘including those needed to supply utilities.",  
"A shortage of food led to malnutrition, disease, and rampant crime and violence.",  
"A series of strikes in 1947 caused massive stoppages in public transport and other services."]
```

But I am not finding a way to know which Items from the list constitute the sentence..
I basically need a mapping like `{sentence 1: (line 1 ,line 2) ,  sentence 2: (line 3,line 4)}`

I need such a mapping for retaining the co-ordinate info (mentioned above) when I go from lines-->sentences

The OCR service I am using is azure form recognizer

Comment: Just a hint: before tokenization, join the original text fragments with a made-up "end-of-line" marker, such as an underscore or a dollar sign (something that does not occur in the text). You can later use the markers to map the sentences to line numbers. Example: `tokenize(" $ ".join(text))`.

Comment: adding such marker will unfortunately prevent spacy/nltk  from sentence tokenizing properly

Comment: No it wont.Have you tried?